# List Custom Post Type Archive link only if it Has Posts in it

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Having a lot of trouble with this one. Each of my Custom Post Type has an archive_page that will display posts under it. I need to display a List of links to each archive page only if it has post under it.

I can list all of my Custom Post Types no problem but when I try to check if it is empty it breaks. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it but have been struggling with it for a while. Thanks for your help.

***List CPT Template***

```
<?php 
    if( have_posts()) :  the_post(); 
        get_template_part('content','weather_alerts');
    endif; ?>
```

***Weather Alerts***

```
$post_types = get_post_types( array ( '_builtin' => FALSE), 'objects');
    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type => $properties ) {
        if ( $properties->has_archive) {
            /* Doesn't work, nothing shows up(!empty($properties)){ code here }*/
            printf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a><br>',
                    get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ),
                    $properties->labels->name
                );
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is **`wp_count_posts`** ([Codex Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts))

You can pass in the post type, and it will return an object with the number of posts for each potential status, e.g.

```
[publish] => 10
[trash] => 0
[draft] => 1
etc...
```

To get the number of published posts for a post-type `my-books-cpt` you would use:

```
$count = wp_count_posts("my-cpt");
$published_count = $count->publish;
```

**Check Post Counts for Post Types**:

To get the count of published posts in your ***Weather Alerts*** php:

```
$post_types = get_post_types( array ( '_builtin' => FALSE), 'objects');
foreach ( $post_types as $post_type => $properties ) {
    if ( $properties->has_archive) {

        // get the count object for this post type
        $count_posts = wp_count_posts( $properties->name);

        // Check if there are any published posts:
        if( isset($count_posts->publish) && ($count_posts->publish > 0)){

            printf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a><br>',
                get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ),
                $properties->labels->name
            );
        }
    }
 }
```

**Display the Post Counts in the Link:**

If you also wanted to display the number of posts in the link, update your `printf` to the following:

```
printf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s (%3$d) </a><br>',
    get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ),
    $properties->labels->name,
    $count_posts->publish // number of published posts
);
```

This will display the links like this (keeping with the book theme):

> Biography (4)
>
> Crime (16)
>
> Thriller (10)